# TimeSeriesWindow with InfiniteFuture returns last observation beyond starting date

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, time-series

I use Wolfram Mathematica 12.1 and want to subset a TimeSeries, but noticed that TimeSeriesWindow returns last observation even for range that does not intersect with the original TimeSeries.

Here is an example:

```
TimeSeriesWindow[
   TimeSeries[Transpose[{#, Range@(Length@#)}]],
   {{2022, 1, 1}, InfiniteFuture}] &@(DateRange[{2000, 1}, {2002, 
    1}, {1, "Month"}])
```

So intuitively this should return nothing as $t_{min}$ is {2022, 1, 1} for TimeSeriesWindow, but the TimeSeries ends earlier at {2002, 1}.

But it does and returns `TimeSeries[{{{2002,1},12.1}}]`.

While if I use something like {2100,12,1} instead of InfiniteFuture M will correctly return an error stating that there are no values.

So is it just me? Can you reproduce it? What am I doing wrong?

2021-06-29 update:  [CASE:4832536] created with Wilfram Support